# ¿Se puede abrir una nueva vista en ionic, pulsando sobre una imagen?

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Tengo un menú que muestra imagenes, en las cuales al pulsar sobre ellas quiero que me muestre una nueva **vista** (Una vista de Ionic).

Una vista propia de Ionic, no el navegador o cosas asi.

Es posible hacer esto..? Gracias!! **:D**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo tienes que añadir un evento click a tu componente y vincularlo a un metodo que finalmente haga el push a la vista que deseas

***html***

```
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" (click)="abrirVista()">
```

***ts***

```
abrirVista(){
  this.nav.push(HomePage);
}
```